# Unexpected value of "this" in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events

The reference to `this` in a callback attached as listener to different elements changes unexpectedly.

Clicking one of the three inner DIVs, it correctly points to them, but when the container is clicked for the first time, the reference is stuck on it.
Am I missing something?

```js
function callback(e) {
    this.innerHTML += '<br/>' + e.type + ' on ' + e.target.nodeName + '#' + e.target.id;
    console.log(this);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(div, i) {
    div.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
});
```

```css
#container { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px; background: #fcfcfc; }
#container div { width: 200px; min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccf; margin:5px; padding: 10px; background: #eef; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  I am the container.
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the container you're overwriting its content - including the child divs and their event handlers. Don't use `.innerHTML` for this. Use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

```js
function callback(e) {
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br/>' + e.type + ' on ' + e.target.nodeName + '#' + e.target.id);
    console.log(this);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(div, i) {
    div.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
});
```

```css
#container { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px; background: #fcfcfc; }
#container div { width: 200px; min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccf; margin:5px; padding: 10px; background: #eef; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  I am the container.
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to bang my head against a wall.

Answer (score 2):

you can use element.append() instead of element.innerHTML to resolve your problem. because `innerHTML` will remove all childNodes then create new instance childNodes so all event listener will be removed

```js
function callback(e) {
    this.append(` ${e.type} on ${e.target.nodeName} ${e.target.id} `)
    console.log(this);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(div, i) {
    div.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
});
```

```css
#container { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px; background: #fcfcfc; }
#container div { width: 200px; min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccf; margin:5px; padding: 10px; background: #eef; }
</style>
```

```html
<div id="container">
  I am the container.
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to bang my head against a wall.